# Preventing users from entering non-digits in input text field with React native

Tags: event-handling

I dont want to allow user to type the alphabets in the input as per the same functionality of keypressevent of jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a `TextInput` Component white the prop `keyboardType = {"number-pad"}`

import { TextInput } from "react-native";

then use it as

```
<TextInput
   keyboardType = {"number-pad"}
   // add more props ...
/>
```

for all the props you can add see this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#props)

Comment: In the ipad it is showing alphabets also and we can able to enter those values also

Answer (score 0):

Try `replace` method in JS by replacing non alphabet character with empty string.

**Code**

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { inputText: '' };
  }

  onChanged (text) {
    this.setState({
      inputText: text.replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, ''),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 200}}
        onChangeText={(text)=> this.onChanged(text)}
        value={this.state.inputText}
      />
    );
  }
}

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => UselessTextInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check by using the `isNaN()` JS built-in function in your input to prevent the user to type alphabet letters;

```js
const Text = "hello";

const Number = "1234";

console.log(isNaN(Text)) // true

console.log(isNaN(Number)) // false
```